# How to test against TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() on Travis-ci

Tags: c#, .net, time, .net-core, travis-ci

I have a test code including the lines below. The code simply returns a suitable time zone based on the known offset, as the name of the time zone will not be used later. the parameter has an integer as offset so that I can query it.

```
timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().FirstOrDefault(tz => tz.BaseUtcOffset.Hours == param.Offset);
return timeZoneInfo;
```

On Travis-CI, I get the error below.

```
Error Message:
   Test method Foo.Tests.SomeClassTests.TimeZoneAbbreviationTest threw exception: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'timeZoneInfo')
  Stack Trace:
      at Foo.TimeZoneInfoExtensions.Bar(TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo) in /home/travis/build/user/Foo/Foo/TimeZoneInfoExtensions.cs:line 11
   at Foo.SomeClass.set_TimeZoneOffset(Int32 value) in /home/travis/build/user/Foo/Foo/SomeClass.cs:line 26
   at Foo.Tests.SomeClassTests.TimeZoneAbbreviationTest(String name, String abbr, Int32 offset) in /home/travis/build/user/Foo/Foo.Tests/SomeClassTests.cs:line 47
```

I assumed the dotnet core `TimeZoneInfo` class is cross-platform but it seems like it is not. I am considering using NodaTime but I tried to keep it simple to have the proof-of-concept as soon as possible. So I am working on **dotnet core 3.1.** with **MSTest** for now. You can see the `.travis.yml` file below.

```
language: csharp
mono: none
dotnet: 3.1
solution: Foo.sln
script:
  - dotnet restore
  - dotnet test
```

Is there a way to work this out as it is supposed to work cross platform? Or, should I give up?

Edit: After a few minor refactoring to specify the source, it's seen that the issue is only about UTC-12.00. The LINQ query returns null when the offsed is -12.

Comment: `GetSystemTimeZones` returns a list of time zones installed on the system.  This just means there may not be a time zone installed for UTC -12

Comment: According to a map of the world's time zones, the only two places in the world that have a timezone of UTC -12 are two uninhabited islands (Howland Island and Baker Island), which is likely why the time zone database doesn't have a timezone for them.

Comment: Well, Linux `tz` has IANA database for timezones while Windows has its own written to registry. A business application may choose to omit the unnecessary bits but an OS cannot, or at least should not.